# Can I wake up a MacBook using a timer?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, wake-up, timer

I would like to learn if it is possible to wake up a MacBook (running Mac OS X 10.6) from sleep using a timer? Is there such a application for Mac OS X? I would like to wake up a computer and turn on iTunes.

Comment: trying to make an alarm clock out of your macbook, huh?

Comment: Why not? It is nicer to wake up listening to  favorite music or a radio station.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need for a separate app with Snow Leopard, this functionality is built into the operating system.

Look at the Energy Saver panel in System Preferences. Click on the `Schedule…` button.

You can create an event with iCal a few minutes after your wake up schedule and have it run a script like:

```
tell application "iTunes"
   set this_playlist to playlist "alarmPlaylist"
   play this_playlist
end tell
```

Comment: question here is if that would work even with closed lid - and how to do it in case it wouldn't.

Comment: AFAIK, MacBookPro requires kernel mod to run awake with closed lid other than clamshell mode (connected to screen+keyboard).

Comment: Build in Schedule wake up work only if power adapter is connected.

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend –––

There are at least two apps that do exactly what you ask:

- Embraceware's [Awaken](http://embraceware.com/awaken/) @ $10 (CAN)
- Metakine's [Aurora](http://www.metakine.com/products/aurora/) @ $14.95

They both are capable of waking a Mac on timer and playing iTunes upon waking.

(I don't have enough points to post this as a comment, which is where it belongs.)

Answer (score 0):

If you do a search for 'timer' at MacUpdate.com you'll get a ton of hits. I can't recommend one over another because I don't sleep my Macs but there are ratings and reviews of all the apps.

Comment: Regarding searching, exactly this is the reason why I asked this question :).